# Как указывать авторство в Android, iOS приложениях?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-development, in-app-purchases

Здравствуйте.

Я начинающий разработчик, столкнулся с проблемой внутриигровых (in-app-purchase) покупок. Небольшая предыстория:

Долго делал приложение с помощью фреймворка Ionic v1, и когда нужно было выложить приложение в iOS, Apple забраковали его в связи с тем, что покупка абонемента, которая делается на сайте клиента, должна присутствовать в приложении и совершаться через систему платежей Apple. Вроде бы с командой разобрались, связались с клиентом, они согласны, главное выпустить приложение на iOS, но тут нас смутили пара нюансов:

Если покупка будет происходить в их приложении на нашем аккаунте iTunes Connect, то деньги будут приходить на наш банковский счет? (Если не так, поправьте пожалуйста) То соответсвенно им нужно будет создавать свой аккаунт, на который мы выложим их приложение. Отсюда следующая проблема: нам важно что бы авторство приложения оставалась за нами. И в описании, или еще где-либо была указана наша компания.

Собственно и вопрос, как лучше поступить: можно ли перенаправлять средства от приложения на нашем аккаунте на банковский счет клиента? Или на аккаунте клиента как то оставлять авторство?

Спасибо за Ваши ответы!

Comment: Если это не игровой абонемент, например - возможность посещения какого-нибудь подземелья в игре, а реальный, - например абонемент на поход в фитнес клуб в реальном мире, но проводить такую покупку через iTunes необходимости нет.

Comment: @RamilGabdrakhmanov Так вот в этом и проблема, что подписка, в данном приложении это подписка в фитнес клубе, но все равно Apple не разрешили опубликовывать приложение основываясь на то, что необходимо покупать эту самую подписку через внутренний магазин.

Comment: Думаю, что имеется ввиду то, что запрещено делать покупки на внешних от приложения сайтах. 

Но, это не значит, что нужно интегрировать инаппы. Посмотрите, как устроены приложения по доставке еды. Я не видел ни одного, которые использует это. 

Думаю, вам стоит взглянуть на Stripe. Эта сервис, который может помочь вам продавать пользователям услуги. Аккаунт в этом сервисе может создать заказчик, а вам просто дать доступ